# Change background color of disabled listbox in windows classic theme

Tags: wpf, themes, aero

I am developing a WPF application that must run using Windows Classic theme. The application creates a dialog box containing a ListBox.  When the dialog box is shown, it must be disabled for 1s before accepting any input.  I am accomplishing this with a style trigger, and it works.  However, the ListBox shows a white background when it's disabled, which I can't seem to get rid of.  When using the aero theme, the following style resource fixes the issue:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
```

But when using Windows Classic theme, the white background reappears.  How can i remedy the situation for Classic theme???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After further research, I discovered that the Windows Classic theme uses WindowBrushKey instead of ControlBrushKey.  Therefore, this fixes the issue for both Aero and Classic themes:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    </Style.Resources>
```