# In WPF, why is the ListBox white?

Tags: wpf, themes, wpf-controls

I'm trying to define an app-wide theme in WPF. I started with making the default window background dark. In my global resources (currently in  App.xaml), I have set the following

```
<Application x:Class="f12dotnet.ThemeSandbox.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#444" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have a `ListBox` in my UI, and it remains white. Setting `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` to transparent doesn't help.

In the [default ListBox template](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/Themes/XAML/ListBox.xaml), I see a setter at the very top, setting the `Background` property (as I would expect) to `SystemColors.WindowBrushKey`. Despite this, the background is white.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBox}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
```

Using `DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource` tells me the source is `DefaultStyle`, which means, per MSDN:

> Source is from a setter in the default style. The default style comes from the current theme.

So where is that?

Further down the `ListBox` template, I noticed the following:

```
<!-- [[Aero2.NormalColor]] -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABADB3" />
```

I suspect that's what responsible, as out of desperation, I actually searched the WPF GitHub repo for "#FFFFFF", and found nothing interesting other than this. Interestingly, it defined here in the control template, not in [the Classic theme XAML](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/Themes/PresentationFramework.Classic/Themes/Classic.xaml).

- **If this is the value's source, can I "override" this brush** the same way I'm overriding `SystemColors.WindowBrushKey`?
- Is there an approach I haven't even though of?
- Or **is creating a default style** for ListBox (and who knows how many more controls), setting the Background to Transparent, **my only option**?

---

PS: At this point, I realize even if I did override the `ListBox.Static.Background` brush, I'd still have to do the same for many other controls, so creating default styles (that inherit from one base style) actually seems like the better way.

I'm just curious, deep into the rabbit hole and wanted to pin-point the origin of the white background and "stop it" right there.

Also, someone apparently [faced a similar problem a decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594714/change-background-color-of-disabled-listbox-in-windows-classic-theme) and managed to resolve it the way I wanted and expected it to work. Yet it's not working for me, or today, or in Windows 11.

Comment: I recommend defining your own color resource keys and resources. WPF is not consistently using the predefined resource keys in the default templates of the framework controls. That's why overriding the key doesn't always work. It works for some controls, for others it doesn't. And whether it works or not is also theme depended as it is natural that some themes use a different color scheme.

Comment: @BionicCode I definitely could, but I'm not trying to create a full blown complex theme, but rather trying to "turn the Classic theme dark"; making it as minimal as possible. I did notice the inconsistencies, but I want to see how far I can get with the absolute bare minimum of re-templating.

Comment: Now you know how far you *"can get with the absolute bare minimum"*, because you *"did notice the inconsistencies"*.

Comment: I guess you had more success when using UWP or any other framework that targets Windows Runtime. Theming, especially system themes like Light and Dark as well as accent colors, is natively supported.

Comment: For minimal effort, I would recommend using an existing theme where someone did all this tracking down of brushes and re templating for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to check which template is actually used in your element. I doubt that this will be the template you provided a link to. This template uses "Value="{DynamicResource". This worked, as far as I remember, before Windows 8. And solutions with overriding system keys did the job perfectly in Windows 7.

It doesn't work now. Therefore, in most cases, the brush is specified in the same place where the Template is specified. And the link to it occurs using "StaticResource". Which means it cannot be overestimated outside the template.

You can get the template that is used by your element in your configuration in the following way:

1. In the Studio designer, open the XAML that contains the element you need (usually for this I create a new test empty window with one element);
2. In the designer (visual form), right-click the context menu;
3. In it, select the item “Edit template” -> “Edit copy”;
4. After which a dialog box with parameters will be shown - set the ones you need;
5. Click “OK” and you will receive the template used by your element.

In my case, this is what the ListBox template obtained in the specified way looks like:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For what reason in Templates abandoned "DynamicResource" with system keys - I cannot tell you. I haven't tried to look deeply into this issue.
At the same time, for some resources they were left as before. Note the `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>`